# Rotate a vector of n dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it possible to rotate a n-dimensional vector into another n-dimensional vector of same length but rotated by a fixed angle $\theta$ with n $\ge$3?

Comment: Kindly help me out.

Comment: I wanted a rotation matrix similar to that in 2 dimensions which when multiplied with my original vector gives me a rotated vector.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434543/how-i-can-rotate-a-m-dimensional-vector?rq=1) The Clifford algebra approach is neat, but confusing when first met. The second answer gives a more pedestrian approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!
Let X ∈ R^n be a given vector 
Take any Orthogonal Matrix (say A) of order n×n
Operate A on X
 [A][X]=[Y]
The resultant vector Y is also in R^n
Such that ‖X‖=‖Y‖
as X and Y have same magnitude, the vector Y is just a rotation of vector X

Comment: thanks very much but i wanted the new vector y to be rotated by an angle $\theta$

Comment: In relation to my answer, ¿about what axis or better, in what plane?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible using the vector representation of $SO(n)$, the group of rotations in n-dim space. However as it stands your question is under-defined... You want to rotate by angle theta but have not specified the axis of rotation (in 3d we would rotate about a specific axis, such as the z-axis or some other specific vector).

Now if you look at the form of the Lie algebra, $so(n)$ of the group $SO(n)$, you will see they are labelled by two indices, $i$ and $j$. Why? The generator $J_{ij}$ generates a rotation in the $i$-$j$ plane: in $n>3$ a rotation is defined by the plane in which the vector is to be rotated (for $n=3$ the choice of axis of rotation uniquely fixes a plane that is orthogonal to it but in higher dimension there are multiple planes orthogonal to a given vector). So the effect a rotation in the $y$-$z$ plane is generated by (exponentiating) $J_{23} $.

For the generators see the discussion at http://www.phys.nthu.edu.tw/~class/Group_theory/Chap%25207.pdf for example.